# Countermodels in Predicate Calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Team,
I need to give a counter model for $\exists x \forall y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \rightarrow (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$.

To do that, though, I'm trying to paraphrase this into a sentence in English. I'm having trouble. Can anyone help me with the paraphrase so that I can get thinking about the counter model?

Comment: I presume you meant $\exists x\forall y$ or $\exists y\forall x$. Which is it?

Comment: I have made the relevant corrections.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh .. there is really no fluent reading of this in English that will actually help you further understand what this statement is claiming.

So, instead, just work with the formula and see how we can make it false.

So, how can we make $\exists x \forall y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \rightarrow (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$ false? Well, that would be the same as making $\neg \exists x \forall y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \rightarrow (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$ true, and bringing the negation inside, that statement is equivalent to:

$\forall x \exists y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \land \neg (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$

OK, so we clearly need at least two different objects, otherwise we cannot have both $Rxy$ and $\neg Ryx$, so let's say we have $a$ and $b$, and so when we let $x=a$,  we need $Rab$ and $\neg Rba$. OK, so now we also need $\neg (Raa \leftrightarrow Rbb))$, meaning we need exactly one of $Raa$ and $Rbb$, so let's say we have $Raa$ but not $Rbb$.

Are we there? No, because while the $\exists y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \land \neg (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$ is true for $x=a$, it is not true for $x=b$, since we cannot pick $y=a$ for $x=a$.

OK, so we need a third object $c$, so that we have $Rbc$ and $\neg Rcb$, and since we need $\neg (Rbb \leftrightarrow Rcc)$ and we don't have $Rbb$, we do need $Rcc$.  But that means that for $x=c$ we can neither pick $y=a$ nor $y=b$ to make the $\exists y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \land \neg (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$ true, so we need a fourth object $d$!

OK, so we have $Rcd$ and $\neg Rdc$, and since we have $Rcc$ we need $\neg Rdd$.  OK, can we make  $\exists y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \land \neg (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$ true for $x=d$ by picking $y=a$? Yes, as long as we make we make sure that $Rda$ and $\neg Rad$.

To sum up, then, the counterexample is one that has $4$ objects in the domain, call them $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and where we have $Raa$, $Rcc$, $Rab$, $Rbc$, $Rcd$, and $Rda$, and no other pairs in relation $R$

Comment: Can I not have a counterexample with one a and b in the domain and s.t. Rab and Rbb? In other words, I don't quite get a why that counter model does not suffice.

Comment: I've done the truth truth for what the negated statement that the claim is equivalent to, and I have an open branch where Raa, $\neg Rba$ and Rab. So, why can that not just be a diagram of my counter model, a model with two things in the domain and <a,b> and <a,a>?

Comment: @Rusty Wait, you know truth trees?!?  Anyway, it does not work with that interpretation, for  the original claim $\exists x \forall y ((Rxy \land \neg Ryx) \rightarrow (Rxx \leftrightarrow Ryy))$ would be true: just pick $x = b$.  Why? because for any $y$ that you pick (whether $a$ or $b$), the conditional is true. Why? Because in both cases the antecedent is false

Comment: But if the negation of the original formula has an open branch, the negation is true. and that's what i want to show, yeah?

Comment: @Rusry Yes, you have the right idea (you're working with a truth tree, right?) But a branch is only open and finished when it all universals it conatins has been instantiated with all constants.  I am certain that in your branch you have a universal that is not instantiated with the $b$, and oince you do that, you'll see you need a $c$!

Comment: For the negation of the formula, I'm first doing a substitution instance on the universal and getting $Ray \land \neg Rya) \land \neg (Raa \iff Ryy))$. And giving an instance of $\exists$ we get the formula $Rab \land \neg Rba) \land \neg (Raa \iff Rbb)$. Then by $\land$ elimination I get $RaB$ and $\neg Rba$, and two open branches after I apply the rule for the biconditional and I can get a counter model on either branch, no?

Comment: @Rusty Yes and no ... *eventually* you'll get an open and *finished* branch, but at this point you're not finished. Like I said, the branch is only finished when all universals have been instantiated with all constants. You have only instantiated the universal with $a$, and you still need to instantiate it with $b$ .. so you have a good bit more work to do before you get an open and finished branch

Comment: But if that's the case, then it seems like my counter model will not have a finite domain, contrary to both of us?

Comment: @Rusty  Ah, yes, excellent question and good thinking!!  OK, it's a bit of a long story, but here's the thing: just because a truth tree gets infinitely long branches does not mean that there cannot be a finite model. Sometimes there is a branch that is open and finite ... but sometimes there really isn't ... and that's because of how most books present the decomposition rule for the existential, saying that you have to use a new constant when instantiating the existential. Now, the thinking behind that is that just because you use 'a' and 'b' does not mean that they have to be different .....

Comment: @Rusty ... and maybe it could be the case that 'a' and 'b' refer to the same object. In fact, when identities are involved, a tree may forced that once a statement $a = b$ appears. Still, the rule as it is usually presented does lead to the problem that some trees do not have any finite and open branches even though a finite model exists. Fortunately, this problem is easily resolved by changing the rule as follows: when instantiating an existential, create a branch for each existing constant and in which you instantiate the existential with that very constant ......

Comment: @Rusty ... and have *one more* branch where, if all the other branches fail to work out, you actually introduce a new constant.  Notice that in my Answer I effecticely follow that same line of thinking: I only introduced a new object/constant when I had to: I first pointed out that I could not stick to one object 'a', i.e I could not set $y=a$ for $x=a$ (and in fact for any constant 'c' you cannot set $y=c$ for $x=c$,so that's why I introduced $b$. And before intrioducing 'c', I pointed out that I could not set $y=a$ for $x=b$ ... and I said that for $x=c$ I could not use $y=a$, thus needed d

Comment: Can you explain this passage? I am finding difficult to understand what it means evaluate an interpretations and understand the passage of testing the "truthiness" when applying constants. 

Are we there? No, because while the ∃((∧¬)∧¬(↔)) is true for =, it is not true for =, since we cannot pick = for =.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose "Rxy" translates "x loves y". Then the sentence could be translated back into awkward English as:
"Someone is such that if they love but are unloved by everybody, then they love themselves if and only if everyone loves themselves".
The English translation doesn't really help to show this, but it's a tautology, so there is no countermodel.